# Intutition behind triple integrals between two surfaces

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I am attempting to learn multivariable calculus on my own. A problem in my book asks me to evaluate
$$
\iiint_\mathcal{W} xz \, \mathrm{d}V
$$
where $\mathcal{W}$ is the domain bounded by the cylinder $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} = 1$ and the sphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 16$ in the first octant ($x, y, z \geq 0$).

The answer is $\displaystyle \frac{126}{5}$.

However, I cannot obtain this number nor can I understand the logic behind evaluating such an integral. If suppose, I take the $z$ variable, I can see that it can vary from $z = 0$ to $z = \displaystyle \sqrt{16 - x^2 - y^2}$. That reduces the integral to
$$
\frac{1}{2}\int_{lowX}^{highX} \int_{lowY}^{highY} x(16 - x^2 - y^2) \,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
$$

My first question is what is this quantity, physically?

Next, as I look down from the $z$ axis --which I have eliminated, I see two curves on the $xy$ plane --an ellipse $\displaystyle \frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{y^2}{9} = 1$ and a circle $x^2 + y^2 = 16$. So, if I vary $y$ from $0$ to $4$, $x$ goes from $\displaystyle 2\sqrt{1-y^2/9}$ to $\sqrt{16-y^2}$.

Hence, my next question is what is so special about $z=0$? Why would I look at the curves on that plane? Why not the plane $z=1$? Is it because this gives me the maximal domain on $x$ and $y$ --a way of saying telling me the extent to which the variables vary? Or am I wrong to reason along these lines?

P.S.:- I better be wrong, because along these lines I do not get $126/5$. I get $3592/81$.

Comment: If you want proper understanding with intuition of setting of such limits,refer Thomas calculus..it is given beutifully there..(book is available online)

Comment: Thanks. I have that book too. But it does not explain very well (in my opinion) the point I am confused about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given this (a priori infinitely long) vertical cylinder whose base is an elliptical disc $E$ in the $(x,y)$-plane  with semi-axes $2$ and $3$. In addition we are given a sphere of radius $4$. Note that $E$ is completely inside this sphere, but the sphere cuts off the cylinder, making   round top and bottom surfaces of the resulting cylindrical body. Actually we don't want the full cylindrical body, but only the part ${\cal W}$ of it in the first octant. We are then told to compute the integral
$$\int_{\cal W} x z\>{\rm d}V=\int_{E'}\left( \int_0^{\sqrt{16-x^2-y^2}} x z\>dz\right){\rm d}(x,y)\ ,\tag{1}$$
whereby $E'$ denotes the part of $E$ in the first quadrant. On the RHS at each point $(x,y)\in E'$ a vertical stalk has been erected, with lower end at $z=0$ and upper end at $z=\sqrt{16-x^2-y^2}$ on the sphere. The body ${\cal W}$ is the union of these stalks. Now
$$\int_0^{\sqrt{16-x^2-y^2}}  z\>dz={z^2\over2}\biggr|_{z=0}^{z=\sqrt{16-x^2-y^2}}={1\over2}(16-x^2-y^2)\ .\tag{2}$$
At this point the spherical shaped top boundary of ${\cal W}$ is completely taken care of. We now
plug $(2)$  into the RHS of $(1)$, and obtain
$$\eqalign{\int_{\cal W} x z\>{\rm d}V&=\int_{E'} {x\over2} (16-x^2-y^2)\>{\rm d}(x,y)\cr  &=\int_0^3\left(\int_0^{{2\over3}\sqrt{9-y^2}}{x\over2}(16-x^2-y^2)dx\right)dy\ .\cr}$$
Note that the $\int_{E'}$ integral is completely in the $(x,y)$-plane. In order to compute it "by reduction" we have drawn at each level $y\in[0,3]$ a horizontal beam beginning at $x=0$ and ending at $x={2\over3}\sqrt{9-y^2}$ on the right half of the elliptical boundary. The reason for this choice of integration order is that we wanted to make good use of the factor $x$ in the integral. In this way no square roots will appear in the calculation.

Calculate the inner integral (with respect to $x$, while $y$ is held constant). You obtain a polynomial in $y$, which you then have to integrate from $0$ to $3$. The result is indeed ${126\over5}$.

Comment: Thanks @christian-blatter but shouldn't the second integration run from $2/3 \sqrt{9-y^2}$ to the boundary of sphere? As you have set it up, we get the summation over the region within the ellipse but I feel we have to get the summation over the region between the ellipse and the sphere. Or did I get something wrong?

Comment: I am making this as the answer because the correct interpretation of this problem is to think of $\mathcal{W}$ as the region inside the cylinder and capped by the sphere.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a figure is worth 1000 words:

[image]

The integral is:

$$\int\limits_{x=-2}^2 \int\limits_{y=-3\sqrt{1 - x^2/4}}^{+3\sqrt{1 - x^2/4}} \int\limits_{z = -\sqrt{16 - x^2 - y^2}}^{+\sqrt{16 - x^2 - y^2}} x z\ dx\ dy\ dz$$

Of course the value of this integral is $0$ because for any position with $+x$ there is a corresponding point with $-x$, cancelling each other out.

Comment: I notice a couple of things --first, you did not place the individual infinitesimals ($\mathrm{d}x$, $\mathrm{d}y$, and $\mathrm{d}z$) in strict order --why is my book so fastidious about it? Is it a difference between formal and informal styles? Second, why can we drop the $z$ dependence like that? What is the reason the $y$ limits look like an ellipse --for one --right where the sphere and the ellipse intersect we get a very different curve. Also, not important (as I am not looking for the solution) but the problem is for the first octant.

Comment: The sphere and the curve intersect at $\displaystyle \frac{5}{9}y^2 + z^2 = 12$

Comment: @user1player1:  The order of integration is typically 1) any integral in which the limits depend solely on a single variable (here, $x$); 2) any integral in which the limits depend solely upon the variable and previously integrated variables (here, $y$ and the previously integrated $x$); 3) etc....  It is not essential to perform these in this order but it is convenient and conventional.

Comment: Thanks. And could you please also clarify my second point?